# H3 Geospatial Index's Projection and Aperture Selection

Tags: gis, hexagonal-architecture, h3

Interested in the H3 design.

From my understanding, the H3 is using azimuthal equidistant projection, which preserves distance and direction from a central point, but brings the area distortion.

H3 is trying to balance the area distortion and conformal distortion. However, based on this article (https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/20964471.2022.2094926),
[image: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/20964471.2022.2094926]
the area distortion is significant when compared with other grid systems.

So why not use the Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection similar to the ISEA (Icosahedral Snyder Equal Area)-based approaches?

Also curious about the hexagon hierarchical structure. There are several "Aperture" selections, such as 3,4,7,9.
[image]

How do we define the "smooth" transition between resolutions? Is there any measurement?

Thanks.

BTW - Does that mean Uber's operation does not care about the cell's equal area across the whole global tessellation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H3 uses icosahedral face-centered gnomonic projections. This is much faster than the ISEA projection, and projects great circle arcs to/from straight line segments. The system was designed for market place dynamics in individual cities, so equal area across the globe was not important.